# Embedded A-Frame scene in Jupyter Lab (Python)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, aframe, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to show a A-Frame scene in JupyterLab, in a Jupyter notebook, from Python code. But I cannot find the way. The scene can be, for example, this (just a simple one):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js" 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="aframe" style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
type="text/javascript"></script>
      <a-scene embedded>
        <a-box position="0 0 -4" color="red"></a-box>
      </a-scene>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying, after reading some references, with:

```py
import IPython
IPython.display.HTML('<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>')
aframe = '''<div id="aframe" style="height: 300px">
<a-scene embedded>
<a-box position="0 0 -4" color="red"></a-box>
</a-scene>
</div>'''
IPython.display.HTML(aframe)
```

I get a blue cell, with a "JupyterLab" label, and loading dots (similar to a A-Frame scene loading), forever. If I look in the console, I read:

```
A-Frame:warn Put the A-Frame <script> tag in the <head> of the HTML *before* the scene to ensure everything for A-Frame is properly registered before they are used from HTML.

Uncaught Error: A a-node type is already registered
    Aframe 18
```

Since the warning is about injecting the script in the header, and after reading [this reference](https://gist.github.com/gnestor/f1893e0226ced227e910f11b769adc06), I wrote:

```js
%%javascript
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '//aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    console.log(window.AFRAME);
```

And then, in another cell:

```py
import IPython
aframe = '''<div id="scene" style="height: 300px">
<a-scene embedded>
<a-box position="0 0 -4" color="red"></a-box>
</a-scene>
</div>
'''
IPython.display.HTML(aframe)
```

Curiously enough, this works when I run those two cells in a notebook for the first time. But if I shutdown the Jupyter kernel, launch it again, and just load the same notebook with those two cells, I get the blue cell again (without even running the cells). If I look at the head element in the HTML page, the A-Frame script element is there. But if I run (in another cell):

```js
%%javascript
    console.log(window.AFRAME)
```

I get `undefined` in the console.

I'm a bit out of ideas. Maybe something related to the order in which scripts (A-Frame and Jupyter scripts) are loaded?

I'm using Firefox, just in case that matters.

Any idea?

Comment: Wrap everything into an iframe, see https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/d3-in-jupyterlab/11367/4?u=krassowski

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was trying to do it without an iframe, but maybe that's the most reasonable way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @krassowski, here we have some code that works:

```js
from urllib.parse import quote
import IPython

content = quote(
        """
        <html>
            <head>
                <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <a-scene embedded>
                    <a-box position="0 0 -4" color="red"></a-box>
                </a-scene>
            </body>
        </html>
        """,
        safe=''
    )
html = """
    <iframe
        width="400"
        height="300"
        src="data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,{content}"
    ></iframe>
    """.format(content=content)
IPython.display.HTML(html)
```

which produces this output when run in a Jupyter Lab cell:

[image: Screenshot of the result, showing a red box]